# How to call reloadData() from within protocol function

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols

I have a semi-complicated setup:

I have a UITableViewController which implements a protocol called CustomCellProtocol, and which uses custom cells, and which sets itself as the delegate of the custom cell.  The custom cell has UIButtons within it.

What I want to happen is that a user taps a button within the custom cell, and some action is performed, and then the table is reloaded.  In order to do this, I needed to create this protocol-delegate setup.  Here is the relevant code:

```
protocol CustomCellProtocol {

    func didTapStar(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int)
    func didTapShortList(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int)

}
```

Within the TableViewController:

```
func didTapStar(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int) {
        // This is called by a function within the custom cell
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
}
```

Within the custom cell class:

```
@IBAction func toggleReadStatus(sender: UIButton) {

    bookage.toggleReadStatus(sender.tag, state: "yes")
    delegate.didTapStar(self, tag: sender.tag)
}
```

Happily, this entire setup works, the model is updated as expected, up until I need to call tableView.reloadData().  For some reason this is either not being called, or is is being called before the rest of the code involved executes.  I suspect I need to find some way to force the reloadData() to execute after everything else, but I am not completely sure what is going on here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your situation. It works.

### UITableViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: CustomCellProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension ViewController: CustomCellProtocol {

    func didTapStar(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func didTapShortList(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int) {

    }

}
```

### CustomCell

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomCellProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didTapStar(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int)
    func didTapShortList(cell: UITableViewCell, tag: Int)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomCellProtocol?

    @IBAction func toggleReadStatus(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapStar(self, tag: sender.tag)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for attempting to help!  I tweaked my implementation to match yours exactly and I am still seeing the same behavior.  The tableView is not refreshing so I still suspect that reloadData is not being called in the correct order.

Comment: I have discovered the problem.  reloadData is in fact being call correctly, and after the model data is changed by the button. My problem was that I was using an old copy of the model data during reload.  Once I moved my 'let dataArray = bookage.dataArray()' out of the viewDidLoad method and into cellForRowAtIndexPath, my problem went away.